# Using XmlReader with Yii - Class 'backend\components\XMLReader' not found

Tags: php, yii, yii2, xmlreader

I have this error:

> PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException Class
>   'backend\components\XMLReader' not found.

I'm working with the framework Yii and want to use `XMLReader` inside a component.

```
<?php 

namespace backend\components;

class XMLRead {

    public function parse() {
        // Instanciation de la classe XMLReader
        try {
            $xml = new XMLReader();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $e->getMessage();
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you please share that code?

Comment: ?php 

namespace backend\components;

use Yii;



class XMLRead{
    
    
    public function parse(){
        
            // Instanciation  de la classe XMLReader
            try{
                $xml = new XMLReader();
            }
            catch(Exception $e){
                $e->getMessage();
            }

Comment: @elmehdim'fallah what libxml version you are using ??

Comment: I am using XMLReader

Comment: Actually iam having libxml ver 2.6.22 in my version. I also face this problem

Comment: Try `new \XMLReader()`.

Comment: is your PHP Version is outdated. Please check this also.

Comment: Thank you @rob006 it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you're using `XMLReader` class inside of `backend\components` namespace so `XMLReader` is interpreted as `backend\components\XMLReader`. You should either use leading backslash to indicate that class from global namespace should be used:

```
$xml = new \XMLReader();
```

Or import this class using `use` statement in head of your file:

```
<?php 

namespace backend\components;

use XMLReader;

class XMLRead {

    public function parse() {
        // Instanciation de la classe XMLReader
        try {
            $xml = new XMLReader();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $e->getMessage();
        } 
    } 
}
```

You can read more about namespaces in [documentation](http://php.net/manual/pl/language.namespaces.basics.php).

Answer (score 0):

You should use XmlReader for examole

`use omgdef\fias\console\base\XmlReader;`

I do not know which packege do you use. But  for this is worked

https://github.com/OmgDef/yii2-fias

Also here is some example form the repo

https://github.com/OmgDef/yii2-fias/blob/aa8980fb40a003697d873df3829b4a440923144f/console/controllers/FiasController.php

You should use the namespace which is in your project